# How do I convert string to an object type or any other type at runtime in C#

Tags: c#, string, object, reflection, typeconverter

I am trying to populate Class Member values as follows:

```
 var myData = new OrdersData(o.symbol)
                        {
                            Account = accountName,

                            Side = (OrderAction) Enum.Parse(typeof(OrderAction),o.side, true) , 

                            Type = o.type, (Cannot convert string to OrderType)                               
                        };
```

The type mentioned above is of the below type:

```
public OrderType Type { get; set; }
```

where **OrderType** is again derived from:

```
public struct OrderType
    {
        public OrderType(object Value);

        public bool IsValid { get; }
        public object Value { get; }

        public override string ToString();
    }
```

So, how do I convert my value (String) to this type (Object)?
Anyhelp is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Create a method that converts a string into an instance of this type, and then call that method...we can't know how you plan to translate the strings you have into the types of that struct that you want.

Comment: What string? You can't just convert arbitrary strings to objects of different types; that doesn't make sense.

Comment: I do not know which part of the question you guys were unable to understand. I got what I wanted from #user245146. A Big thanks to him and I also thank Servy for his response. And it sucks to get my reputation reduced when I recently joined StackOverflow just because some of you have no time to read/understand the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming, OrdersData.Type if of OrderType and o.type is string,

```
var myData = new OrdersData(o.symbol)
{
    Account = accountName,
    Side = (OrderAction) Enum.Parse(typeof(OrderAction),o.side, true), 
    Type = new OrderType(o.type),
};
```

Comment: Great!!! ThanQ #user245146. I appreciate your response. I do not know how I missed this one and I do not understand where I went wrong with my question that these stackoverflow members #Ant P,#L.B,#John Kraft,#p.s.w.g and #karthik could not be able to understand my question thereby marking my reputation lower..!